# Filling gaps between staircase and plaster wall

Tags: walls, plaster, stairs, gap

I purchased a home that was a two family converted to single. Brick veneer on the outside and block inside. I have been assured by two structural engineers that I have no foundational issues. I have a gap developing between the staircase and the wall. The previous owner just lazily sealed the gap with caulking which as shrunk and pulled apart. So I went through with a flat blade and started peeling the caulking off between the staircase and the wall. In some places, there's almost an inch gap. The block can be seen underneath the plaster. What is the best thing to use to help close the gap?

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]
[image]

Comment: Any idea what's causing this? I would be concerned with fixing the root cause before patching up the crack. Is this something that has developed since you took possession of the house?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I think it is just minor movement but the caulking had started to pull apart. I don't see the staircase dropping at all.

Comment: Interesting. Is this movement since you bought the place or just the caulking giving out? Are those your "notes" on the wall?

Comment: No movement, just the caulking. This is after I went in with a scraper to remove it. I put some dates on the other cracks on the wall where the bad patch work they did was also not holding up